# Reading the value from text file and updating it to a field in sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have atext file with data like

Patient name: Patient1 Medical rec #: A1Admit date: 04/26/2009  Discharge date: 04/26/2009
DRG: 982 and so on.

In the format as given above i am having several records in text file.each field is separated by colon

I have to read this file and find out values and update corresponding fields in my sql table.Say drg value 982 has to be updated in drg column of  sql table)

Please help in doing it through sql query or ssis package.

Answer (score 0):

If I get this task I'll use SSIS.

- Create 2 DataSources: flat file (for text file) and SQL Server connection
- Use Lookup task to lookup value from text file for each record in the db table
- Use execute SQL Task to update records by lookuped value

Answer (score 0):

You MIGHT try doing this by means of BULK INSERT.

- Create a temp-table to get hold the new values
- BULK INSERT the file into said table (**)
- [optionally do some data-enrichment/cleaning here]
- merge the information from the temp-table into the actual table

The only problem with this MIGHT be that

- the server cannot access the file directly (eg. when the file is on a
  network share)
- the file is of a format that can't be handled by BULK INSERT

Given the example data above you might need to load the data into one big column and then do the splitting into different columns by means of creative-sql (PatIndex, substring, the works...). You might try giving colon as a field-separator, but you'll still end up with data that needs (quite a bit) of cleaning.